# Retrieving Make, Model, and Device Type Details in Matter App Development using Google Home Sample App (GHA)

Tags: android, iot, google-home, google-smart-home

I am new to Matter app development and seeking assistance. I am trying to retrieve details such as Make, Model, and device type for a Matter device. While exploring the Google Home sample app (GHA), I could only find deviceType, vendorId, and productId. Is there a method to obtain the additional information I need?

```
override fun onCommissioningRequested(metadata: CommissioningRequestMetadata) {
  Timber.d(
    "*** onCommissioningRequested ***:\n" +
        "\tdeviceDescriptor: " +
        "deviceType [${metadata.deviceDescriptor.deviceType}] " +
        "vendorId [${metadata.deviceDescriptor.vendorId}] " +
        "productId [${metadata.deviceDescriptor.productId}]\n" +
        "\tnetworkLocation: " +
        "IP address toString() [${metadata.networkLocation.ipAddress}] " +
        "IP address hostAddress [${metadata.networkLocation.ipAddress.hostAddress}] " +
        "port [${metadata.networkLocation.port}]\n" +
        "\tpassCode [${metadata.passcode}]")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve details such as make, model and device type for a Matter device by enrolling yourself to the developer preview of the Google Home API. You can refer to the latest Google IO [video](https://developers.home.google.com/io) tutorial in this regard to get an idea of the capabilities that are being now supported to make developer's interaction with matter devices smoother.